# Unable to read data from an Arduino to a C++ Program

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port

I'm trying to read data sent by an arduino using the serial port using a C++ program.
I can see that the Arduino is sending some data; the devStatus variable shows a non zero value and dwRead is getting updated with 4, but the buffer is still blank. I have tried a bunch of things like setting the timeout using the COMMTIMEOUTS structure.
Here is my Arduino code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    HANDLE hCOM;
    DCB dcb;
    BOOL bPortReady;

    hCOM =   CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM15",GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    bPortReady = SetupComm(hCOM,10,128);
    bPortReady = GetCommState(hCOM, &dcb);
    //populate variables in the DCB strucutre
    dcb.BaudRate = 9600;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcb.fAbortOnError = TRUE;
    dcb.fOutX = FALSE;
    dcb.fInX = FALSE;
    dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
    dcb.fRtsControl = FALSE;
    dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;
    dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE;  
    bPortReady = GetCommState(hCOM, &dcb);

    char lpBuffer[5];
    DWORD dwRead;
    COMSTAT devStatus;
    BOOL rFile;

    ClearCommError(hCOM, NULL, &devStatus);

    if(devStatus.cbInQue>0)
    {
        //The read function returns true, but no Data is getting read.
        rFile = ReadFile( hCOM ,  &lpBuffer , 4, &dwRead,0);
        printf("Read : %s",lpBuffer);
    }
    else
        printf("Nothing in queue");
        _getch();
}
```

Excuse my formatting and bad programming skills, I'm a surgeon who's been trying to learn to program and it's my first post here.

Comment: We use Arduino's with my high school robotics team to team new students how to program.  We show them how to get input into the Arduino.  It seems like you want to send data from the Arduino back to a Windows PC.  Is that right?  If you just want simple text, the Arduino development tool has a console windows that shows the output.  Sorry that I don't remember enough about how to read a COM port from a Windows app to help, if that's really what you need to do

Answer (score 1):

Your posted code calls GetCommState twice. I suppose you meant to call SetCommState for the 2nd one.

Another problem is that printf expects the buffer to be terminated with nul ('\0'). So zero out the buffer or lpBuffer[dwRead] before passing it to printf.

If dwRead returned with 4 then you did get 4 bytes. Use the debugger to see what is in the buffer. Maybe it is not printable characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
ReadFile( hCOM ,  &lpBuffer , 4, &dwRead,0);
```

lpBuffer is already a pointer.  Taking the address of that is not what you want.  Instead, write

```
ReadFile (hCOM, lpBuffer, sizeof lpBuffer, &dwRead, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks wallyk, I tried that but it still doesn't help. I've declares lpBuffer as char lpBuffer[5] and the value of dwRead is updated to 5 after using ReadFile